# Как вывести JS-массив

Tags: геолокация, json, javascript, ajax, php

Добрый день!

У меня есть на javascript массив-библиотека:

```
$jsonData = {"product":{"id":310,"title":"Наименование","short_description":"Короткое описание","full_description":"Описание"},"prices":{"270":{"price":399,"old_price":800,"delivery_price":79,"tax_price":0,"upsale_price":0,"geo_key":"UA","name":"Украина","currency":"грн.","rate":0.37,"phone_template":"+38 067 927 25 74","address_template":"01024, г. Киев, ул. Богомольца, д.5, кв.9","name_template":"Карпенко Ярослав Федорович","active":true},"271":{"price":1695,"old_price":3380,"delivery_price":295,"tax_price":0,"upsale_price":0,"geo_key":"RU","name":"Россия","currency":"руб.","rate":1,"phone_template":"+7 928 827-22-53","address_template":"135999, Москва, ул. Ленина, д.10, кв.5","name_template":"Петров Петр Петрович","active":false},"272":{"price":12129,"old_price":24000,"delivery_price":1768,"tax_price":0,"upsale_price":0,"geo_key":"KZ","name":"Казахстан","currency":"тенге","rate":5.3,"phone_template":"+7 705 1301111","address_template":"ул. Майлина, д.3, кв. 6, г. Костанай, 110003","name_template":"Алтынбаев Азат Тюлегенович","active":false},"336":{"price":45,"old_price":91,"delivery_price":8,"tax_price":0,"upsale_price":0,"geo_key":"AZ","name":"Азербайджан","currency":"манат","rate":0.027,"phone_template":"+99 455 873 53 38","address_template":"1025, Баку, ул. Юсифа Сафарова, д. 6, кв 13","name_template":"Низами Гянджеви Ильяс","active":false},"356":{"price":20449,"old_price":40898,"delivery_price":3630,"tax_price":0,"upsale_price":0,"geo_key":"AM","name":"Армения","currency":"драм","rate":12.1,"phone_template":"+37 499 35 22 62","address_template":"0010, Ереван, ул. Вардананц, д. 3, кв. 54","name_template":"Григорян Ашот Багдасарович","active":false},"357":{"price":350000,"old_price":700000,"delivery_price":40000,"tax_price":0,"upsale_price":0,"geo_key":"BY","name":"Беларусь","currency":"бел. руб.","rate":280,"phone_template":"+37 529 186 24 65","address_template":"220035, г. Минск, пр-т Машерова, д. 76, кв. 17","name_template":"Матвеев Евгений Алексеевич","active":false}},"lowPrice":{"year":"2014","month":"04","day":"14"}};
```

И есть возможность получить страну на PHP 
?country_code=UA

Как мне сделать чтобы если UA были выведены параметры по сайту с geo_key: "UA" из библиотеки?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Во-первых не $jsonData, а `var jsonData`. javascript не php. А во-вторых отформатируйте код, а то читать не возможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот [так](http://ideone.com/vqY9bQ)

Comment: превосходно) как теперь это вывести в html без php?

Comment: @delighter, а подумайте)

Comment: <span id="name_template"></span> ?

Comment: кстати, без php вывести не получится. в html коде все равно должны быть пхп вставки

Comment: так как их проставить по сайту просто <?=$delivery_price?>

Comment: Вы умеете php в html-e выводить? где вы взяли эту переменную $delivery_price?

Comment: через echo умею :) только как их переменные назвать:))
$prices['price']
$prices['name_template']
?

Comment: в шаблоне foreach($prices as $price) и погнали...